# Conditional probability of dependent RVs

Tags: conditional-probability, random-variable

The Gaussian random variables $Y_{1}\epsilon N(4.5,9.5)$ and $Y_{2}\epsilon N(4,4.5)$ exist. The joint pdf $f_{Y_1Y_2}(y_1,y_2)$ of two gaussian random variables are equal to

$f_{Y_1Y_2}(y_1,y_2)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_{Y_{1}}\sigma_{Y_{2}}\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}exp\bigg(\frac{-1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\bigg [\bigg (\frac{y_1-\mu_{Y_1}}{\sigma_{Y_1}}\bigg )^2-2\rho\frac{(y_1-\mu_{Y_1})(y_2-\mu_{Y_2})}{\sigma_{Y_{1}}\sigma_{Y_{2}}}+\bigg(\frac{y_2-\mu_{Y_2}}{\sigma_{Y_2}}\bigg)^2\bigg]\bigg)$

Since they are correlated (and dependent),$\rho =0.7071$. The objective is to write an expression for the theoretical conditional probability $P(2<Y_2<3|Y_1>5)$ by calculation or estimation by any means.

Comment: Just a little hint, use $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$

Comment: @DeepNorth Yes, but what is $P(A\cap B)$? Since they are dependent it cannot be calculated as $P(A)P(B)$.

Comment: You already have the joint pdf, it can be calculated from the joint pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More suggestions $$P(2<Y_2<3,Y_1>5)=\int_2^3\int_5^\infty f_{y_1y_2}(y_1,y_2)dy_1dy_2$$

Note you already know the $f_{y_1y_2}(y_1,y_2)$

This is $P(A\cap B)$

Then you also know the distribution of $Y_1$ which is $N(4.5,9.5)$ from here you can calculate $P(Y_1>5)$. This is $P(B)$

Comment: And how would you evaluate the integral?

Comment: here already have the μ1 and μ2 and ρ, it should be an explicit function for the bivariate normal